# Get the list of tables created on any date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I stuck in a situation where I want to find which tables I've created on sql server on date 14 september 2012 (14/09/2012).

Is there any query which will list these tables are created on this date.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.tables
WHERE create_date >= '20120914' AND create_date < '20120915'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.tables
WHERE   CAST(create_date AS DATE) = '20120914'
```

Comment: +1 but to work if the OP is on a CS collation you need to use `sys.tables` and `create_date`

Comment: I honestly had no idea that could make a difference. I've edited the answer and thanks. Every day is a school day!

Comment: Is for me as well. I'm on a CS collation and my comment about `SYS.TABLES` is definitely correct but actually it doesn't seem fussy about the casing of the column names for some reason. Both `Create_Date` and `create_date` work (though intellisense doesn't like it)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS table_schema_name, name AS table_name
FROM sys.tables
WHERE CAST(create_date AS DATE)= '201209214;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from sys.tables where cast(create_date as date)='2012-09-14'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
        [name]
       ,create_date
       ,modify_date
FROM
        sys.tables
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),create_date,103) = '14/09/2012'
```

**[sys.tables (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)**

Returns a row for each table object

**[sys.objects (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)**

Contains a row for each user-defined, schema-scoped object that is created within a database.

Answer (score 0):

martin-smith answer is right and There is so may ways to do write this query one of this,

```
 select * from 
 ( 
      SELECT *, convert(varchar,create_date,103) as tdate FROM sys.tables 
 )as t
 WHERE t.tdate = '27/09/2012'
```

Regards
Amit Vyas