# Is there any way to get list of tables by created on date.?

Tags: mysql

i found some answers but i found some answers here: [Get the list of tables created on any date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620229/get-the-list-of-tables-created-on-any-date) but im getting, sys.tables doesn't exists.
i know here `sys` is database name.

Comment: That link is for sql-server. What version of MySQL are you using? If you are using MySQL..

Comment: im using mysql 5.7.26

Answer (score 2):

Look into `tables` table in `information_schema` db. Query below:

```
SELECT table_schema,table_name,create_time 
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  table_schema=*your_database_name
AND    table_name=*your_table_name;
```

Replace *your_database_name and *your_table_name accordingly.

Edit: sorry, your question is to lookup by created date.. here's the query:

```
SELECT table_schema,table_name,create_time 
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  DATE(create_time)="yyyy-mm-dd"
```

You can try it here : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n1yPjJKhyMLkWSP25htovn/0

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find by a particular created date then:

```
 SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME' 
 AND CREATE_TIME = '2019-12-23 17:41:05'
```